# xpath expression to get to a value based on other values

Tags: xpath

I have the below xml and I want to be able to get to the tel value where the type value = 1.

I have attempted quite a few different scenarios and got to the following;
`//Telephone/type[text()='1']/parent::tel` but this is not working. Please can someone help.

```
<Telephone>
    <Number>
        <tel>01242123456</tel>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <CountryDiallingCode>+44</CountryDiallingCode>
    </Number>
    <type>1</type>
</Telephone>
<Telephone>
    <Number>
        <tel>07777777777</tel>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <CountryDiallingCode>+44</CountryDiallingCode>
    </Number>
    <type>3</type>
</Telephone>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try 
    //Telephone[type = '1']/Number/tel